# Odd - page shows up blank inside an iframe. Why?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to set up a web-based control panel for some hosting customers that use WordPress.

As you probably know, the URL for administrating a WordPress site is http://domain.com/wp-admin.  For example:

http://minutebookreview.com/wp-admin
(this is just a random blog)

Now, look what happens when I try to load this page inside an iframe using this code:

```
<iframe width=640 height=480 src="http://minutebookreview.com/wp-admin"></iframe>
```

You'd think this would work, right?

Well, have a look for yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/A4MxE/

The page simply shows up blank inside the iframe.  The wp-admin login page won't load.

Anyone know why this is happening?  It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: what's the point in loading wp admin into iframe?

Comment: Well, I want to do it for a certain user experience I'm trying to give.  Let's not worry about why I want to do it though, let's see if we can figure out how to make it happen. :)

Comment: Yes, people really like random strangers loading their site's admin panels remotely.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're getting after...

Comment: @MikeC8 I think Col.Shrapnel is pointing out that this *technique* could very well be used to fool people into entering sensitive information on a site facading as another.

Comment: @MikeB - The technique of using an iframe? :)  Sure.  But what I am trying to do here is take the *customer*'s wordpress admin and iframe it in another site, which is effectively the reverse of stealing the customer's information...I am getting them to input their information into their *own* site even when they are on another.

Comment: And **why** would they want to access their own site from within another?  If it were mine, I'd just want to be on my own site from the start.

Comment: @Sparky672 In order to provide an "admin panel" for customers, so that they can easily open up their wordpress admin as well as configure other aspects of their site all from one consistent interface, with a persistent menu of options, one of which is the wordpress admin panel.

Comment: In 2011, an `iframe` is not the way to go for such a thing.  Just use a shiny Wordpress logo and have it open in another page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I saw.  It seams wordpress just dosen't like you.

[image: Oh no.]

Comment: Hey, thanks.  This helps a lot actually.  For some reason this error wasn't being displayed in my browser.

Comment: For those who are curious, this answer helped me track down the problem.  The server is returning this header: "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN".  This header instructs browsers to disallow iframing on other domains.  So, if you have control over the wordpress sites (as I do), then it's just a matter of getting this header removed.

Comment: @MikeC8, Did you even ask yourself _"why?"_ the `sameorigin` header is there in the first place?  Do you even care about the security of your customer's site?

Comment: I guess I'm still not sure what the security issue could possibly be that could be caused by putting the customer's *real* site inside another one.  The worst case scenario is that the customer believes they are logging into a site that is *not* their own, when it really is?  I'd love for someone to explain the actual risk of this.  Everyone on this thread seems more interested in just saying "it isn't a good idea" without saying why, though...Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @MikeC8, in SO you have to address another person with `@username` or they'll never get notified.  Regarding your question, there's an hosting account exploit where an attacker injects a bogus `index.html` page so all of your other pages are then contained inside an invisible iframe.  The user does not know since the pages look normal, however code on the injected page is stealing your login info among other things.  Wordpress does not allow one to open it's Admin panel within an iframe so this type of exploit is rendered harmless.... until somebody removes that feature.

Comment: @MikeC8,   Wordpress sites are huge targets of spammers & attackers since there are millions of them.  Their bots troll the Internet looking for any Wordpress site with an open security hole.